# Mustache expression does not render in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

It seems like my vue.js code does not have any effect on my website. How do I fix this?

```
const selector = new Vue({
  el: '#hej',
  data: {
    question: 'How was your service?',
    selectorValue: '',
    buttonClicked = 'lorem ipsum'
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="hej" class="section">
    <p class="question">{{ question }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`buttonClicked = 'lorem ipsum'` should be `buttonClicked: 'lorem ipsum'`